# Why component is not working in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

i am trying to make button and after make button i want to make ad event lisner on by click on this button it will show some message but i am able to create only button but not able to add event listener on it.please help me on it.

```
function Button()
{
    return (
        <button id='btn'>Masai</button>
    );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(Button());
function showAlert()
{
    return(
        <p>You clicked Masai!</p>
    );
}

const msg=ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#message'));
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',()=>{
    msg.render(showAlert());

})
```

[error described in image in console part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3wc4.png)

Comment: You need to add event handlers in React not outside it, new docs will guide you
https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/responding-to-events#adding-event-handlers

Comment: this is not how things should be done in reactjs. please refer to the docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html#learn-react) and learn reactjs a little before asking any question like this one here.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way that you are trying to do in react.

In Your Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
    import './index.css';
    import Button from './Button';
    import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
    import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
    root.render(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Button/>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
    reportWebVitals();
```

In Your Button.js

```
 function Button() {
    
    const clickEvent = () => {
    
      alert("You clicked Masai!");
    }
    
      return(
             <button id='btn' onClick={clickEvent}>Masai</button>
        );
    
    }
```